# How to Select rows by bad formatted column

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a very old database, where someone didn't keep valid format for data.
So in my Column I have got values like that:

```
in column is   1234567890             expected   1234567890
in column is   12-345-678-9-0 foo     expected   1234567890
in column is   bar 1234-567-890       expected   1234567890
in column is   12-34567-foobar-890    expected   1234567890
etc.
```

I mean, there is a number (always 10 digits), with some other characters in random places.

I have got in my variable `$number` the integer value of 10 digits.

I want to do some query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column = $number`, but I want to match all rows that has got this `$number`, if I would clean my column to right format.

I have no idea, how can I do this :(

Comment: If the incoming data is validated now, you can update all rows once using for example a regex to strip all invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

To convert data from this alphanumerical column I see two possibilities:

1. Read all entries from the table (via php, as you already specified as tag), change it with a regular expression `$newValue = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $oldValue);` and update the database entry with that value.

or

2. Use a user defined function like [MySQL UDF RegExp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) to do that directly with a MySQL update statement.

Comment: Did this information help or is there still something open?